# Elasticsearch is being really slow when returning all results

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticutils

I have an index of ~113000 documents.  I'm trying to retrieve all of them, and I don't care about the score.  basically a select * from index;

And i'm doing this in python using elasticutils (haven't found the time to switch to elasticsearch-dsl yet)

Running

```
S().indexes('da_userstats').query().count()
```

completes in about 0.003 seconds.

Running

```
S().indexes('da_userstats').query()[0:113595].execute().objects
```

is taking about 15 seconds.

From what I understand of the documentation both should forcing execution, so I don't see why there is the huge difference in time.

In the mapping I've tried marking the fields as don't analyze but its had no effect.  I really don't get why there is a difference of so many orders of magnitude.

```
@classmethod
def get_mapping(cls):
    return {
        'properties': {
            'id': {
                'type': 'integer',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False,
            },
            'email': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'username': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'date_joined': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'last_activity': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'last_activity_web': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'last_activity_ios': {
                'type': 'string',
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
```

Comment: This way of returning all documents is not the Elasticsearch way. Use [`size`/`from` or pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html) to do this. If you would have had more documents or smaller heap size you would have run out of memory doing it like this.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the documents, and you don't care about the order, you may want to use the scroll and scan API, which is very fast.

Comment: @AndreiStefan in elasticutils slicing is the way of specifying size and from, and looking at pagination, they advise against doing it when you want to go through all the documents.

Comment: @MauricioRoman Going to take a look at that thanks, sorting it afterwards in python might be faster as well because its not doing it on every shard and then once at the end